# OWIN interferes with log4net

Tags: c#, debugging, log4net, owin, tracesource

In my application, I've got the following logging strategy/appenders:

- **DebugAppender**: If the root level is DEBUG, write every message that matches DEBUG to the default trace listener output
- **ConsoleAppender**: If the application mode (global context property) is 'console', write every message above WARN to the console ouput
- **EventLogAppender**: If the application mode (global context property) is 'service', write every message above ERRROR to the console output
- **RollingFileAppender**: Write every message above INFO to a rolling flat file

This works very well throughout the whole application, until the very first line I'm starting the OWIN web host using the `IAppBuilder` interface. As soon as I invoke `WebApp.Start`, I noticed the following behavior:

- Debug messages (ILogger.Debug) are getting written to the console output
- Debug messages (ILogger.Debug) are getting written twice to the VS debug output

Upon further investigation, I figured out that OWIN silently attached an instance of `System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener` and `System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener` to the default trace/debug ouput, which may be the root of the problem. However, declaring the `DefaultTraceListener` in app.config explicitly didn't help.

Is there any way I can configure OWIN to be less... sneaky?

Comment: which is a pity because it seems a well thought out issue. I would of edited it rather than downvote but hey...Also I can't help.

Comment: @xvdiff - this is a professional place. Swearing is not acceptable.

Comment: "Please note that expletives are not allowed." ~ the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: Now you stuck in a loop arguing over the title...Seriously, next time just don't swear

Comment: @Doorknob Oh, it's in the guidelines. Well then.

Comment: @Liam Agreed. But now I have plenty of time arguing because by experience, no one is interested to answer a -5 question. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the listener in startup code, eg:

```
Trace.Listeners.Remove("HostingTraceListener");
```

(Name from [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/release/src/Microsoft.Owin.Hosting/Engine/HostingEngine.cs#L287))

Comment: Why also remove "HostingTraceSource"? (As it does not appear to be a listener..)

Comment: Are you removing the listener before log4net is configured?